# How to convert IList back to List<T> in a BindingSource?

Tags: c#

```
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
    source.Add(new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });

     //List<string> theList = source.List;//compile fail.  Can't convert from IList to List<T> implicity
     List<string> theList = source.List as List<string>;//fail, null
```

I've seen people online creating a method to perform an explicit conversion.  This seems like total overkill for this task.  Is there a better way to get my list back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're adding a `List<T>` as the first item in the list.

To retrieve it, you would write

```
(List<string>) source.List[0];
```

---

Your code would work if you actually bind to a `List<T>` by setting the `DataSource` property.